# Google place id

Tags: google-places-api

My activity baggage drop service in Barcelona,
Present in google map, but without a visible address, because we go to the customer, not the opposite.
I could not find the place id.
Anyone can help me, with this special case?

Answer (score 0):

I understand the place is the following:

https://www.google.es/maps/place/bds+Baggage+Drop+Service/@41.4784879,1.7394724,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x12a4a2da9f22f0ff:0xe342bbdfbf6f867b!8m2!3d41.410367!4d2.1758622

Is it correct?

Now if you use the following place ID finder page and search 'bds Baggage Drop Service'

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder

you will see that the place ID is ChIJ__Ain9qipBIRe4Zvv9-7QuM.

Now you can find a place via Places API:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJ__Ain9qipBIRe4Zvv9-7QuM&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Hope it helps!

Comment: Dear, thank you very much!! I was putting the name without bds at the beginning... it's a stupid mistake! Your answer help me a lot. I thought that the id place finder was working even without writing the exact name of the business.